# How do we get the font size of elements in native view using appium

Tags: java, css, selenium, appium

Is there a way to get the font size of text in the native view using appium?

i know we have

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("by-id")).getCssValue("font-size");
```

for web views. is there a way for native views aswell?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get font style properties of text in native app using appium.

Comment: It can be converted to comments also.